# Внезапно UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

при старте программы сталкиваюсь с такой историей, как победить?

извиняюсь, я не знаю как правильно, офорить, текст из dos ниже. python 3.6,3 установлен.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid
continuation byte

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <class 'UnicodeDecodeError'> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SoundGrain.py", line 59, in <module>
  File "SoundGrain.py", line 41, in __init__
  File "Resources\MainFrame.py", line 236, in __init__
    self.check(auDriver)
  File "Resources\MainFrame.py", line 243, in check
    self.driversList, self.driverIndexes, selected = checkForDrivers()
  File "Resources\audio.py", line 36, in checkForDrivers
    driverList, driverIndexes = pa_get_output_devices()
SystemError: <built-in function pa_get_output_devices> returned a result with an
 error set
[5336] Failed to execute script SoundGrain
```

Comment: Лучше ошибку с трассой скопируйте в вопрос, в таких случаях скриншоты зло -- поиск не работает, скопировать ошибку из вопроса нельзя. Еще нужно указать в метках версию питона

Comment: спасибо, исправил.

Comment: А откуда скрипт `SoundGrain.py`? Кст, имя компьютера имеет кириллицу?

Comment: попробуйте запустить скрипт ещё раз и приведите полный traceback и фрагмент кода, который исключение  вызывает (по traceback строчку нужную посмотрите). Можно перенаправить поток ошибок: `py ваш-скрипт.py 2>errors.txt` и содержимое errors.txt в вопрос вставить (`py -m webbrowser errors.txt` команду попробуйте, чтобы в браузере открыть).

Comment: в начале программы напишите `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`. 
А также сохраните файл в `utf-8` кодировке